# Pieces from PGN viewer are displayed above review bar

Tags: bug, pgn-viewer

A picture + freehand 'circle' says more than a thousand words:

[image]

You can reproduce it e.g. by clicking [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/11595) and scrolling down. Expected behaviour is that the pieces disappear behind the bar, just like the board does. The problem is that both the pieces (`.chess-replayer .board .chess-piece`) and the review bar (`.review-bar-container .review-bar`) have a `z-index` value of 10. Changing the `z-index` of the pieces to 9 solves the problem and does not introduce other issues, as far as I can see.

Comment: Is this still a bug?

Comment: @GaurangTandon yes, I can still reproduce it.

Comment: Ok. Though the link you posted no longer exists.

Comment: I've updated the question with a newer link.

Comment: Thanks for the update.